# organizing data in excel files with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have an excel file that looks something similar to this:

```
**Part**  **Quantity**  **Category**  **Board**
 part1        4            RES         board1
 part2        3            CAP         board4
 part3        2            CAP         board3
              3            CAP         board2
              4            CAP         board4
 part4        3            DIO         board2
```

ad infinitum. Ideally, what I want is something that can take the 5-6 boards listed and create a column for them, and place the respective quantities for each individual part, so in other words,

```
**Part**  **Category**  **Board1**  **Board2**  **Board3**  **Board4**
 part1        RES           4           0           0           0
 part2        CAP           0           0           0           0 
 part3        CAP           0           3           2           4        
 part4        DIO           0           3           0           0
```

I do not require that the other entries be filled with zeros. They can be left as unfilled cells. Keep in mind, I start with excel files that are not grouped as above, which is to say, the part numbers are repeated, and every row is filled. However, I cannot have duplicte parts which is why I use the pandas groupby command to organize them and effectively remove the duplicates. Here is the very simple script I have at present:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import subprocess


#load csv file
df = pd.read_excel('/home/Linux/.../raw-inventory.xlsx')

#group by part number
organize = df.groupby(['Part','Value','Description','Qty','Board']).sum()

#open to .csv
organize.to_excel('organizedlist.xlsx')

#opening outputted file
subprocess.call(organize, shell=True)

print('Done')
```

I've been looking around in pandas and xlsxwriter and I haven't yet seen a good way to do this. Maybe someone on here has an idea?

It may be better to use the original .xlsx file as well, but there would have to be a way to remove duplicate parts. That's why I use the groupby pandas function. It preserves all other data, and eliminates multiple instances beneath the 'part' column. Any suggestions, from simple to complicated, recommended python packages, etc, would be greatly appreciated!